# Hover opacity image change on more images, separately, in same div?

Tags: css

All examples of image swap on hover using the opacity value I've read about use one image in its own div. Is it at all possible with CSS to have three images in a row in the same div, and set a background image for each of them separately, that would separately change opacity on hover and thus visually change the image? The background and foreground images I have in mind are the same size.

Basic three link-images in a row is what I have. I want to set a background image for each of them that would change on hover.

```
<div id="mixnav"> 
<a href="psychill-mixes.html"><img src="images/logo-psychill-final2.png" width="375" height="331" alt="psychill mixes" /></a>

<a href="goa-psy-mixes.html"><img src="images/logo-goa-final2.png" width="393" height="331" alt="goa psy mixes" /></a>

<a href="other-mixes.html"><img src="images/logo-other-final.png" width="364" height="331" alt="other mixes" /></a>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Would you know why my images are not showing up when I use Preben's method?

HTML:

```
<div id="mixnav"> 
<a id="psychillimg" href="psychill-mixes.html"></a>
<a id="goaimg" href="goa-psy-mixes.html"></a>
<a id="otherimg" href="other-mixes.html"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mixnav {
margin-top: 75px;
margin-bottom: 80px;
display:block;
}

#psychillimg{background-image: url(images/logo-psychill-final2.png/375/331/psychill);}
#psychillimg:hover{background-image: url(images/logo-psychill-hover2.png/375/331/psychill);}
#goaimg{background-image: url(images/logo-goa-final2.png/393/331/goapsy);}
#goaimg:hover{background-image: url(images/logo-goa-hover2.png/393/331/goapsy);}
#otherimg{background-image: url(images/logo-other-final.png/364/331/other);}
#otherimg:hover{background-image: url(images/logo-other-hover.png/364/331/other);}
```

What am I missing? I'm not using float in my mixnav div as I have everything centered, and not using sizes as I specify them in imageX css as you described (they are of slightly different widths). The images simply don't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is may be the most easy way. This way you set the images in one place (CSS file), and also easily add specific width to each image:

I have set a `<a> ... </a>` and use CSS to tell it to act as a block and give it a width and height. Then I use CSS to give it a background image, and then a css that tells it to show another image on hover.

The effect will be better by using a pre-loader of the hover-images, but I hope you het the idea.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="image1" href="#1"></a>
    <a class="image2" href="#2"></a>
    <a class="image3" href="#3"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/*same height and width for images - OR you can add special sizes in the imageX css*/
.wrapper a {display:block;height:331px;width:175px;float:left;}


.image1{background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/175/331/city");}
.image1:hover{background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/175/331/animals");}
.image2{background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/175/331/people");}
.image2:hover{background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/175/331/transport");}
.image3{background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/175/331/fashion");}
.image3:hover{background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/175/331/cats");}
```

See example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/exc8snpx/

[image]

**For *transitions* add this to the css:** see Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/exc8snpx/3/

```
.wrapper a {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

To avoid having a "blink" you may use image sprites or use a preloader script.

Comment: can it be made with an opacity transition? Because I need that, it's basically two same images one over the other, only the other is brighter, so I want an ease in/out glow effect on hover

Comment: Apologies for late reply as this is the earliest I've had the chance to test this - please see update in OP.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you?

Comment: You need to use "" around the URL of the images. Like `#psychillimg{background-image: url("images/logo-psychill-final2.png/375/331/psychill");}`

Comment: that didn't change a thing it seems. I'm still getting a completely empty div, no images whatsoever

Comment: I see why. You didn't follow my instruction to add a width and height to the image divs. See my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/0p5jujt6/ :-)